# How to see the reputation graph with years on the X-axis?

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph

[image]

In the above picture the X-axis is shown by month. But is it possible to set it to years?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it already does that. Just see [my profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/785241/daedalus?tab=topactivity).  Note however that I've been active far more often than you have during the years I've been here, so your activity may have something to do with it.

Comment: I believe the axes are chosen automatically, there is no configuration for it.

Comment: @Daedalus No. You cannot alter it.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I never said one could alter it.

Answer (score 4):

> But is it possible to set to years ?

No. You cannot configure it.

You can have more granularity by selecting an area by dragging across the lower chart, however, what you ask for is not possible with the reputation tab as of now.