# Reputation chart in the Activity Tab: Mysterious date range

Tags: discussion, activity-tab

The JavaScript reputation chart in [my Activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2111778/xjcl?tab=topactivity) starts in 2017:

[image]

This seems to apply to most other user profiles as well.

The chart of some users ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8187800/colex-msft?tab=topactivity)) start in February of this year (2020) however:

[image]

The chart starts with 6.9k rep so it can't be the case that this account was only created in Feb 2020. In fact, every profile I've seen starts in 2017 or after Feb of this year.

What is the reason for this discrepancy? Is there a way for users to switch the date range?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307934/how-to-see-the-reputation-graph-with-years-on-the-x-axis?rq=1

Comment: I believe it's related to reputation gains to try and show an increase over the period, if you look at the example user's reputation across all time on [SE main](https://stackexchange.com/users/11156148/cole-xia?tab=reputation), you'll notice they had an extended period of inactivity (or low rep gain) and their graph starts towards the _end_ of that period of activity, likewise for my reputation curve, it starts in 2017, where [my](https://stackexchange.com/users/3963457/nick-a?tab=reputation) reputation started to increase. i.e. it tries to make the graph look pretty?

Comment: I thought that a good train a thought, @Nick, but then [my](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) profile starts at 2017 with a very flat line for a year.

Comment: @Larnu mine starts on August, which seems strange to me.

Comment: I think they try to show some form of "region of interest", but I'm not certain how that is chosen. Three years seems to be the maximum, and shorter times when thats appropriate.

Comment: viewing source on my own page the `var graphData` has exactly 1460 data points. So 4 years. so presumably it actually starts at Nov 11, 2016 even though only 2017 is labelled on the axis

Comment: the other profile you link has exactly 365 data points. So maybe it shows 4 years if you have been a member that long - or just one if you haven't? And 1/3 of a year (122 days) if you are member less than a year (like @10Rep)

Comment: I've been a member since 2015 at least

Comment: yeah, so you would get the 4 years worth. Theory is that anyone who has been a member for >= 4 years sees 4 years, membership >= 1 year and < 4 years, Sees 1 year,  membership >= 3 months and < 1 year sees 3 months

Comment: And the data starts before the label. ColeX's first data entry is `var graphData = [6868,6868,6903` and he has 365 entries in the array so presumably this is from a year ago

Comment: We can see Gordon Linoff was on 475,055 on [8th Nov 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20161108031142/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) and 478,428 on [18th Nov 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20161118082502/https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) and [his graph](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=topactivity) currently starts at  477,410 (I chose him as unaffected by the recalc of rep for questions)

Comment: This question's problem is addressed by [How to get a bigger reputation graph?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357554/how-to-get-a-bigger-reputation-graph)